# regexp_like vs like operator : Oracle

Tags: sql, regex, oracle

I am searching for multiple phrases using SQL 'like' operator. Same results can be extracted using Regexp_like function in Oracle. Which one is better/efficient to use **and why?** My observation is that 'like' works much quicker than regEX.
I am running my queries against very large dataset with few million rows.
Here are both the versions of the query

Using like:

```
select 
     name 
from 
     table 
where 
     lower(result) like '%the condition is absent%'
     or lower(result) like '%partial presence of disease%'
```

Using Regexp_like():

```
select 
     name 
from 
     table 
where 
     regexp_like(lower(result),'^.*(the condition is absent)|(partial presence of disease).*$')
```

Comment: actually you don't only do regexp_like but also do `lower()` operation which may apply an additional impact on performance

Comment: Yes I know @smnbbrv I tried 'i' matching operator of reg_exp too. In my case, lower() worked faster than 'i'.

Comment: I've read the same -- that LIKE is faster than REGEXP_LIKE. I would run your own tests and compare CPU time for the two approaches.

Comment: @DavidAldridge  Thanks. I am trying to understand why. How oracle internally handles these 2 ?

Comment: If you can get what you need with LIKE, there is no need in regex.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew With LIKE, query gets bigger and bigger as you add more and more search terms. On the other side, regexp_like() can just take bigger regEx (but just one function call). So in such cases, I have seen others  using regexp_like. However, since there is significant performance difference, I would like to know how these two work internally and if there is any standard to prefer one over another.

Comment: I would suggest to give a try to INSTR in your tests as well.

Comment: In my experience regular expressions are usually significantly slower than other text functions.  I'm not surprised that REGEXP_LIKE is much slower than a regular LIKE.

Comment: I voted to re-open this, because it's not a matter of opinion whether one is faster than the other in these circumstances -- it can be directly measured quite simply.